# Ubuntu server: disk partitioning without reinstalling the OS

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning

I currently have an Ubuntu server installed, where I host some files. Is it possible to create a new partition on my disk and move the data there, without resintalling the OS?

here is my setup from df-T

```
root@kitsch:~# df -T
Filesystem    Type   1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/kitsch-root
              ext4   237251272  69025564 156174048  31% /
none      devtmpfs      492320       212    492108   1% /dev
none         tmpfs      496904         0    496904   0% /dev/shm
none         tmpfs      496904       324    496580   1% /var/run
none         tmpfs      496904         0    496904   0% /var/lock
none         tmpfs      496904         0    496904   0% /lib/init/rw
/dev/sda1     ext2      233191     33669    187081  16% /boot
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the FS. Ext3/4 doesn't support online resize, and Ubuntu doesn't create a dynamic partition by default. So you are borked with this one.

You can resize by using a liveCD from USB pendrive or using the CD. If its a server, backup and reimage.

Next time try using a normal FS (which is mature, made by experts not by hobby coders) like XFS. Also, you should create a dynamic partition at install. (Other FS are .. JFS for example. Btrfs is still experimental. Ext3/4 is so buggy I'm surprised people use it. (not flame but honestly, I never would advise the usage of it). Reiserfs 3 is outdate , 4 will never be done. So wait btrfs and keep using good FS until then.)

[XFS online resize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS#Online_resizing)
[XFS Features/wiki entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XFS)

However, if you use XFS, you have to create it and use specific mount options. If you don't know how, comment, ask and I'll help you.

When you create it:
`mkfs.xfs -l size=64m`
And this is what you should write into `/etc/fstab` instead of the "defaults":
`logbufs=8,noatime`

[JFS wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JFS_%28file_system%29)